Problem with Root after installation via Homebrew
after installing Root via Homebrew, i get the following problem:
(MacBook Air M1 Sonoma 14.6.1; Xcode version 16.0)
#include <new>
 ^
input_line_1:1:2: note: after modifying system headers, please delete the module cache at '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/root/6.32.04/lib/root'
input_line_1:1:2: note: imported by module 'std' in '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/root/6.32.04/lib/root/std.pcm'
Warning in cling::IncrementalParser::CheckABICompatibility():
  Failed to extract C++ standard library version.
Warning in cling::IncrementalParser::CheckABICompatibility():
  Possible C++ standard library mismatch, compiled with _LIBCPP_ABI_VERSION '1'
  Extraction of runtime standard library version was: ''
Replaced symbol at_quick_exit cannot be found in JIT!
<<< cling interactive line includer >>>: fatal error: module file '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/root/6.32.04/lib/root/Darwin.pcm' is out of date and needs to be rebuilt
Failed to load module Darwin
Failed to load module std
Failed to load module _Builtin_intrinsics
Failed to load module ROOT_Foundation_C
Failed to load module ROOT_Config
Failed to load module ROOT_Rtypes
Failed to load module ROOT_Foundation_Stage1_NoRTTI
Failed to load module Core
Failed to load module Rint
Failed to load module RIO
Failed to load module Foam
Failed to load module RSQLite
Failed to load module Minuit2
Failed to load module MLP
Failed to load module ROOTDataFrame
Failed to load module GenVector
Failed to load module ROOTBrowserv7
Failed to load module RootAuth
Failed to load module Graf3d
Failed to load module ASImageGui
Failed to load module ROOTTreeViewer
Failed to load module Gviz3d
Failed to load module TreePlayer
Failed to load module RooFitJSONInterface
Failed to load module ROOTGraphicsPrimitives

 *** Break *** segmentation violation
[/usr/lib/system/libsystem_platform.dylib] _sigtramp (no debug info)
[/opt/homebrew/Cellar/root/6.32.04/lib/root/libCling.so] ROOT::TMetaUtils::TNormalizedCtxtImpl::keepTypedef(cling::LookupHelper const&, char const*, bool) (no debug info)
[/opt/homebrew/Cellar/root/6.32.04/lib/root/libCling.so] ROOT::TMetaUtils::TNormalizedCtxtImpl::TNormalizedCtxtImpl(cling::LookupHelper const&) (no debug info)
[/opt/homebrew/Cellar/root/6.32.04/lib/root/libCling.so] ROOT::TMetaUtils::TNormalizedCtxt::TNormalizedCtxt(cling::LookupHelper const&) (no debug info)
[/opt/homebrew/Cellar/root/6.32.04/lib/root/libCling.so] TCling::TCling(char const*, char const*, char const* const*, void*) (no debug info)
[/opt/homebrew/Cellar/root/6.32.04/lib/root/libCling.so] CreateInterpreter (no debug info)
[/opt/homebrew/Cellar/root/6.32.04/lib/root/libCore.so] TROOT::InitInterpreter() (no debug info)
[/opt/homebrew/Cellar/root/6.32.04/lib/root/libCore.so] ROOT::Internal::GetROOT2() (no debug info)
[/opt/homebrew/Cellar/root/6.32.04/lib/root/libCore.so] TApplication::TApplication(char const*, int*, char**, void*, int) (no debug info)
[/opt/homebrew/Cellar/root/6.32.04/lib/root/libRint.so] TRint::TRint(char const*, int*, char**, void*, int, bool, bool) (no debug info)
[/opt/homebrew/Cellar/root/6.32.04/bin/root.exe] main (no debug info)
[/usr/lib/dyld] start (no debug info)

I think the problem is the Xcode version
Maybe i should install an old version of root or xcode?
how can i do that?
